Creating a Stripe PaymentIntent with a reference to an internal sales order record
We have built a simple CRM system for our client which includes a basic eCommerce function.
Customers can access the CRM system's customer portal, add items to their basket, then pay via Stripe. When the customer clicks 'Pay Now', the server-side code creates a Stripe Session object, then redirects the customer to checkout.stripe.com. The customer enters card details and is redirected back to the CRM system after a successful payment - this all works fine.
Our client would like to add the facility to accept payments over the phone. In this scenario:

The customer calls the sales agent
The sales agent logs into the CRM system, open the customer's record, and composes a sales order with line items etc
The sales agent then logs into the Stripe Dashboard, clicks 'Create Payment', and enters the card details as they are read out by the customer

The problem in this scenario is that after a payment has been made, there is no reference between the CRM system's sales order record and the Stripe payment. The agent has to manually enter the Stripe PaymentIntent ID into the CRM system in order to create a reference between the sales order and the Stripe payment.
According to the Stripe documentation, it is possible to create a PaymentIntent object via the Stripe API and mark this as a MOTO payment. This involves submitting the customer's card details to the server before sending them to the Stripe API, which is strongly discouraged by Stripe - hence we are excluding this option.
I have tried using the Stripe API to create a PaymentIntent object without supplying a PaymentMethod - I was hoping this would then allow the agent to log into the Stripe Dashboard, navigate to the specific PaymentIntent record, and enter card details - however, in this scenario, the dashboard does not supply any means of paying a PaymentIntent with a status of 'Incomplete'.
My question is - what is the correct way to implement the payment journey where a customer makes a card payment over the phone, the card details are entered by the agent into the Stripe dashboard, and a reference is maintained between the sales order record in the 'calling system' (the CRM system in this case) and the Stripe payment?

unfortunately, there's no other better way I can think of other than what you are already doing

Have you considered using webhooks for your CRM to get information about events happening in your stripe dashboard?
The event payment_intent.succeeded must be what you're searching for.
When agent is creating a payment in strip dashboard, he must put a refference to the order(from your CRM) in payment's description or descriptor.
After the payment is made, stripe will notify your CRM about it by sending a request to the endpoint you specified. Extract PaymentIntent from it and process it.
Scenario

The customer calls the sales agent
The sales agent logs into the CRM system, open the customer's record, and composes a sales order with line items etc
The sales agent then logs into the Stripe Dashboard, clicks 'Create Payment', puts order id into payment's description or descriptor and enters the card details as they are read out by the customer
After payment succeeds, stripe sends payment_intent.succeeded event to your CRM
CRM handles the webhook (extract order id, find the sales order and link it with PaymentIntent)

docs:
stripe webhooks
stripe event types
How payment_intent.succeeded webhook may look:
{
  "id": "pi_3P7iCgHjnVW1Ziy20EHzwb2T",
  "object": "payment_intent",
  "last_payment_error": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "next_action": null,
  "status": "succeeded",
  "amount": 2000,
  "amount_capturable": 0,
  "amount_details": {
    "tip": {
    }
  },
  "amount_received": 2000,
  "application": null,
  "application_fee_amount": null,
  "automatic_payment_methods": null,
  "canceled_at": null,
  "cancellation_reason": null,
  "capture_method": "automatic",
  "client_secret": "pi_3P7iCgHjnVW1Ziy20EHzwb2T_secret_R9k9NIYPjBkqyVzVjCfxLl6rc",
  "confirmation_method": "automatic",
  "created": 1713635998,
  "currency": "usd",
  "customer": "cus_PxdSBM9TI82uI0",
  "description": "57891",
  "invoice": null,
  "latest_charge": "ch_3P7iCgHjnVW1Ziy2098I39F6",
  "metadata": {
  },
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "payment_method": "pm_1P7iCfHjnVW1Ziy22U241A81",
  "payment_method_configuration_details": null,
  "payment_method_options": {
    "card": {
      "installments": null,
      "mandate_options": null,
      "network": null,
      "request_three_d_secure": "automatic"
    }
  },
  "payment_method_types": [
    "card"
  ],
  "processing": null,
  "receipt_email": null,
  "review": null,
  "setup_future_usage": "off_session",
  "shipping": null,
  "source": null,
  "statement_descriptor": "ORDER_123",
  "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
  "transfer_data": null,
  "transfer_group": null
}


Hi @wwsd - many thanks for your suggestion. We explored something similar to this, and I'm in the process of investigating the webhooks facility. However, we're trying to avoid the need for the agent to manually enter the CRM system's Order ID into Stripe - ideally we'd prefer to send the Order ID to Stripe directly from the server, then have the agent open the record from the Stripe end and complete the payment over the phone.
